# How does playing a Meld card as my Commander work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-meld

[Gisela, the Broken Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gisela%2C%20the%20Broken%20Blade) is a legendary creature that melds with [Bruna, the Fading Light](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bruna%2C%20the%20Fading%20Light) to create [Brisela, Voice of Nightmares](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brisela%2C%20Voice%20of%20Nightmares). All three are legendary creatures and as part of the meld action are exiled before returning melded into a new object.

Will the melded card Brisela be considered a player's commander still, for purposes of doing commander damage?

Further, what happens when Brisela leave the battlefield?

Comment: Given we've received a question about melded legendary cards from Brothers War, I've updated this to make it more generically applicable to melded cards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The melded card will be your commander.** If either Gisela or Bruna are your commander at the start of the game, when they meld together Brisela will still be considered your commander for all purposes.

When and if Brisela leaves the battlefield only the original commander half will follow the commander rules for returning to command zone, the other half will behave as any other card would. This is covered in the rulings for both Bruna and Gisela:

> In a Commander game, your commander may be Bruna, the Fading Light or Gisela, the Broken Blade, and the other may be in your deck. If they meld into Brisela, Voice of Nightmares, Brisela will also be your commander; but if Brisela leaves the battlefield, only the card chosen as your commander at the start of the game may be put into the command zone.

Comment: Would Brisela count as a different commander for counting commander damage? Similar to having two commanders with partner. For instance, if I inflict 15 combat damage with Gisela, then meld to Brisela and inflict another 6 combat damage, will I win?

Comment: @MatthewJensen thats a good question, I'd be inclined to say they are treated as the same, but cant fid an official answer on that.